# How use Emojee in python?

Tags: python-3.x, emoji

I wrote a program python 3.6,i want commented in instagram for post.i want use Emojee in my comment,see https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/.
i bellow code in python

```
import emoji
comment(id_pitcure,emoji.emojize('good :wink:'))
```

i put bellow comment for post but  it do not put Emojee.

```
good :wink:
```

how fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, please specify.

Comment: @ bhansa   no ,i do not have error

Comment: add `use_aliases=True` to `emojize()` keyword args

Comment: @Juggernaut,Thank you it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `comment(id_pitcure,emoji.emojize('good :wink:', use_aliases=True))`